# Empty info for PIL.Image.fromarray

Tags: python, ipython, python-imaging-library, jupyter-notebook

My goal is to print inline an image inside a IPython notebook. The image is built with the function `PIL.Image.fromarray`. More specifically, here is what happens. When I run

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import *

image = Image.open('image.png')
image_pixels = np.array(image.getdata())
image_rec = Image.fromarray(image_pixels.reshape(image.size[0], image.size[1]))
image_rec
```

I get a black picture inside the notebook. However, when I replace the last line by `image_rec.show()`, it correctly opens a window with `image` inside.

After looking, I noticed that `image_rec.info` is actually empty `{}` whereas `image.info` contains `{'compression': 'raw', 'dpi': (72.0000084, 72.0000084)}`. What is happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `info` is something the writer adds. Saving the image with some options and reading it back, fills the `info` dictionary:

```
image_rec.save('image2.png', dpi=(72, 72))
im2 = PIL.Image.open('image2.png')
```

Now:

```
>>> im2.info
{'dpi': (72, 72)}
```